# MySQL merge queries when using foreign keys

Tags: mysql

Is there a quick way to select results based on constraints from one table and use the foreign keys obtained from this to select results in the parent table? Or can you only do this with two separate queries?

So achieves the same as this, but in one query (tableB has a foreign key from tableA):

```
Query1: SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE columnN LIKE x
Query2: SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE primaryKey LIKE foreignKeyFromQuery1
```

Comment: Do you mean joining?

Comment: Why does this have a down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select columns in a table and other to get single result mean **JOIN**.
you can use this:

```
SELECT <Table>.<Field>, <Table>.<Field> FROM <Table 1> 
INNER JOIN <Table 2> ON <Table 1>.<Primary Key>=<Table 2>.<Foreign Key> 
WHERE <Conditions>
```

Based on your need, it looks you need INNER JOIN:

```
Query1: SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE columnN LIKE x
Query2: SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE primaryKey LIKE foreignKeyFromQuery1
```

The joins will be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableB INNER JOIN tableA ON
tableB.primaryKey=tableA.foreignKeyFromQuery1 WHERE columnN LIKE x
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean joining tables, then you would do it like this:

```
SELECT table1.column_name, …
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON join_condition
```

You use the syntax `join table_to_join on join_condition` to join tables where references are consistent. Normally the join condition is something like `ON table1.id = table2.id`. In this way, the data is combined without duplicating rows.